# 2 update queries running at the exact same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a situation (which I do, but changing the situation is not an option) where I run a statement such as:

```
Update Table 1 Set Field 5 = 'Blah' Where Field5 IS NULL
```

And that statement runs at the exact same time multiple times, how can I avoid the same row being updated by multiple threads?

Comment: Jeez, my first post to Stackoverflow and I already messed it up: It's

Update Table 1 Set Field 5 = 'Blah' Where Field5 IS NULL

What I have is a processing situation where I need to loop through a table, grab one record at a time, process it, and move onto the next record. But the problem is that I have multiple threads working on this and I've seen situations that lead me to believe that the same record has been "grabbed" by multiple queries at the same time.

Comment: Since you can't change the situation I'll skip the whole set-based operations and why the current situation is a bad idea.  What RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: SQL 2000, SQL 2005, and sometimes SQL 2008

Comment: Is it possible that something like a row lock would help?  Or using transactions and at the point of update check and see if the record is in the middle of another transaction already?  I have full control over the SQL side of things (i.e., the stored procedure that does the update), but I don't have control over the piece that calls the stored procedure multiple times at the exact same moment in time.

Comment: What isolation mode are these running it?

Don't understand how the same record could get updated more than once if the update statement changes the record so that it doesn't meet the where clause.

Also, just to help us understand the context better (besides performance) why is the current state of things a problem

Comment: I believe that because the queries are firing at the exact same time (and because I need to add some more logic to the query (which is why I'm here)) that the update doesn't happen quickly enough before another select grabs the same record.

Comment: It's very random and doesn't happen all the time, but I've seen it happen and I assume the fix is pretty simple.  So I'm looking for the SQL Server syntax to prevent the same record from being operated upon at the same time by SQL.

Comment: A transaction doesn't necessarily help me from what I understand because without some sort of lock on the record as soon as it's selected, I don't see how to prevent another query from selecting it in the milliseconds between the time it's selected and the time it's updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is because of a "made up example" here, but that statement will already only run once for a given record.

Assume that Field5 is null:

```
Update Table 1 Set Field 5 = 'Blah' Where Field5 IS NULL
```

Now Field5 = 'Blah'

Running this statement a second time...

```
Update Table 1 Set Field 5 = 'Blah' Where Field5 IS NULL
```

Will do nothing.  The record will remain as it was from the first update as it is no longer included in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I agree, don't see how the same row would get updated more than once - unless you are providing hints that allow reading of dirty data

Comment: I'm talking about a data set of 1000 or so records, though.  And I'm talking about returning an ID once the record has been updated.  I'm finding that when the query runs simultaneously, grabs a record, updates it, and returns the ID, sometimes the same ID gets returned across multiple threads.

Comment: And I'm not talking about running the query a second time, I'm talking about running it at the SAME time.  I'm sure there's a race condition of some sort where even though SQL is getting the request to run the query 3 times at the same time, SQL puts them in line and doesn't run them in parallel.  But even then I need a way to isolate each request so that once it updates a record and returns the ID of that record, the same ID won't be returned for the query calls that happened (almost) simultaneously.

Comment: I believe that the operation should be atomic, so there is no way that two updates could perform this operation at the exact same time.  However, if the operation is a little more complex and is NOT atomic, wrap the operation in a transaction to MAKE it atomic.

Comment: I may have done a poor job of explaining the problem and in research today I came up with some more info and perhaps something that will work:  I'm going to set the isolation level to serializable.  FlipScript actually seemed to understand what I was getting at best.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) field (known as `timestamp` in older versions of mssql).  Whatever process spawns the threads will need to check the current `rowversion`, and then in your `update` you can have an extra condition in the `where` clause to only update the old `rowversion`.  `rowversion` fields are automatically changed whenever any field in the row is changed, so this will ensure that the modification only happens once.

Note: This is a horrible hack.  You'd be better off fixing your threads to divide up work more intelligently.

Comment: Donnie - I actually agree with you that the "best" solution would be to have the threads only grab work that needs to be done, but he states that he doesn't control the code... only the DB.  Seems like a communication issue is the root of the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also run the updates from a script, while using flock on a (dummy) lock file to get an exclusive lock on the file before the update, and releasing the lock afterwards.